# Can I save my highlights?

Tags: overwatch

I got a sick win a few minutes ago and can watch the highlights in the highlights section. Is there a way to save them somewhere?

Comment: I've been using the recording feature of the Windows 10 Game Bar to get around this for the time being. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/keyboard-shortcuts-for-game-bar. At least until (if?) there is a built-in way to do this.

Comment: i guess you're playing it on pc - if you played on a ps4, by using the **share** button you can save the last 15 minutes of gameplay

Comment: @WayneEra I can use W10's DVR feature (or any screen recorder like obs) too, however Im asking if there is an official, ingame way to do it.

Comment: @ardaozkal yeah i know, but your question has already been answered...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Update: As of [update 1-13](https://fenixbazaar.com/2017/06/23/overwatch-ptr-patch-notes-update-1-13-adds-highlight-exports-with-4k-and-60-fps-recording/) in PTR, you can now export highlights.

> With the above, players can now record any of their “Top 5” or “Recently Captured” highlights, exporting them as a video file to their gaming platform’s designated media library (on console) or directory (on PC). On PC, players will also have the option to select the quality at which these highlights are exported, supporting up to 4K at 60 FPS for Windows 8 or higher operating systems, and up to 1080p on Windows 7.

This is done by going to the highlights section and clicking the record option.

Comment: Great quick answer

Comment: That's a shame. This feels like a bit of an oversight.

Comment: @Fluttershy yes... like the surface of the sun is a bit hot.

Answer (score 6):

With [the recent overhaul of the Highlights system](https://youtu.be/OkYJlPMdWNA) it is now possible to export highlights as video files. It is also possible to record your own highlights, in addition to the automatic ones. Highlights no longer expire as soon as the client is closed, although they do still eventually expire — they must be exported to be saved permanently.

[image]

To export a highlight to save it permanently, go to the Highlights section from the main menu and press the "record" button on the highlight you want to export. (Click elsewhere to review the highlight.) This will present a dialog that can be expanded for settings to control the quality of the export — it will be re-rendered in non-real-time, so you can select the highest settings even if your computer would never really be able to play with them.

[image]

The exported videos will be added to your `Documents` folder, under `Overwatch/Videos/Overwatch/`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but sadly in the beta it's still not available as a feature. Though I'd love to save how I ressed 3 teammates at once with Mercy, or how I smashed a certain pain in the ass opponent in the wall with Reinhardt. Or just simply a few multikills with Bastion.

As for screen recording, if you use win 10, it already has a screen recording function for games, should work with Overwatch too. On basic settings, the recording can be started/stopped with the windows key + alt + R shortcuts. (Or at least I hope these are the basic controls for it, my PC offered me these as basic)

Comment: I do that ATM but I'd prefer an ingame feature to accept as answer. Still upboted

Answer (score -1):

What I did was I opened OBS and just recorded the Overwatch window while playing the Highlight!

Hope this helps!